# iOS app to edit .txt files (w/ Dropbox sync) that preserves Windows-style line breaks

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I commonly edit .txt files on my PC (Notepad) and my Mac (using TextEdit) and store them in Dropbox.  I would like also like to be able to edit these .txt files on my iOS devices.  Every app that I've tried breaks the Windows-style line breaks; if I edit a .txt file, all line breaks are lost when I open that file in Notepad.

Is there any iOS app which can edit .txt files and preserve Windows-style line breaks? (Paid is OK, but cheaper is better.)  I have tried iA Writer and Write 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nebulous Notes](http://nebulousapps.net/notes.html) and [Elements](http://www.secondgearsoftware.com/elements/) both support windows newline characters.